# How do I specify token ordering in pyparsing?

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

Suppose I'm parsing the following line:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

I'd like to parse this as:

```
Words('The quick brown fox') + Literal('jumps') + Words('over the lazy dog')
```

My current pyparsing definition is:

```
some_words = OneOrMore(Word(alphas))
jumps      = Literal('jumps')
sentence   = some_words + jumps + some_words
```

What's happening is that the `some_words` swallows up the '`jumps'`, and I get a parsing error. How do I make pyparsing lex the jumps as a literal token?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are already thinking like the parser, since you understand that `OneOrMore(Word(alphas))` keeps going, even to reading the word "jumps".  Now turn that around and write the parser to do things the way you think.

For every word up to "jumps", how do you know that it should be added to the leading set of words?  You know for each word because it is not the word "jumps". Pyparsing does not automatically do this lookahead, but you can do it for yourself with NotAny (which can be abbreviated using the '~' operator):

```
JUMPS = Literal("jumps")
some_words = OneOrMore(~JUMPS + Word(alphas))
```

Now before matching another word, some_words first verifies that the word is not "jumps".

Comment: So then I have to explicitly exclude every single token I don't want to see? Is there any way to do what lex/yacc do and just specify the tokens in order of acceptance.

Comment: Most pyparsing grammars do just specify the tokens in the order of acceptance. Look through the examples on the pyparsing wiki and see if you get a better idea of how pyparsing grammars are structured. If you are thinking that you want something very generic like `VERB = oneOf("runs jumps walks slithers meanders")` to break up a sentence by parts of speech, then this is more NLTK territory. Or if your grammar is such that identifiers might be mixed with keywords, you may need to define identifier is `~KEYWORD + Word(alphas)` and define KEYWORD as a MatchFirst of all defined keyword literals.